# Svg width not display de leftscale in d3.js heatmap /

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]> The scale is not looking due to the size of the svg on the left, it., I tried to increase the size but it doesn't increase in the svg, Always he cuts my side scale

```
 const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current)

  svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
     


const x = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, width])
          .domain(myGroups)
          .padding(0.1);
          svg.append("g")
             .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
             .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0))
             .select('.domain').remove()
             .attr("font-size", '12')
    
             

const y = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([height, 0])
            .domain(go)
            .padding(0.01);
          svg.append("g")
            .style('text-anchor', 'start')
            .style("font-size", '12')
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
            .select('.domain').remove()[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I change the translation scale of elemento for the render of svg in the 30px left of svg element

```
const y = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([height, -7])
            .domain(go)
            .padding(-0,2);
          svg.append("g")
            .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .style("font-size", '12')
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
            .attr("transform", "translate(52)")
            .select('.domain').remove()
```